# Unable to locate elementary-sdk

Tags: software-installation, development

When a try:

```
sudo apt install elementary-sdk
```

it says

```
Unable to locate package elementary-sdk
```

It's a fresh install of loki.

```
apt update
```

give me a 404 error.

```
Err:7 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki Release                                                                                                 
404  Not Found [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a repository error: there is no Ubuntu version "loki", you should use "xenial" Ubuntu repositories with elementary repositories.

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial main
```

Comment: I will investigate later tonight, but seems to me that `software-properties-common` is messing around with sources list.

Answer (score 0):

I can verify updating "hera" to "bionic" in the following source list files allowed me to install elementary-sdk just now (for Elementary OS 5.1):

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list
```

This appears to be an ongoing issue the past 4 years so I've filed [a bug in GitHub](https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/316) so this gets fixed at its root.